# How do I stop VS Code code from pushing(syncing) to Git, if it's hung up trying to push a large file?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore, git-push

**QUESTION** - How do I stop VS Code from trying to push to Git, so I can add the unneeded large files/folders to gitignore and then proceed to push again?

I upgraded Angular and it created a folder in my project that looks like the image below, with a folder named '.angular'. I forgot to include it in my .gitignore and attempted to stage, commit and push to my Git repo. It's still running (trying to push) 30 minutes later.

I do get a message in the git output that says large file detected:

> [2022-03-21T06:14:33.091Z] > git push origin master [29424ms]
> [2022-03-21T06:14:33.091Z] remote: error: Trace: 47b6ad853b68f1ff7b533b5b9e1e44880272a4bcbf979e9f8afb162aa47ef3a9
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
> remote: error: File client/.angular/cache/13.3.0/angular-webpack/5ebe13da59e6342699441237cc06e261c0793966/35.pack is 113.88 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

[image]

Here is what options I have in VS Code

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by reloading VSCode and just git reset HEAD~1 to the previous commit.

Answer (score 0):

I **guess** the real question you should solve is to remove the huge files from that commit.

You can use <del>`git filter-branch`</del>, [`git filter-repo`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) or [`bfg`](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove the large folders.

If you happened to commit the file *just now* (I mean, the newest commit), you can use `git commit --amend` to survive the newest commit from pushing limit.

---

> ...so I can add the unneeded large files/folders to gitignore and then proceed to push again?

No, it is too late for you to add it to `.gitignore` **now**. Adding it to `.gitignore` now won't remove it from the Git commit history -> won't solve the problem of pushing limit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I committed. My process is always the same - stage, commit, push. In that order. My issue is that it looks like it's still running (or trying to run the push) in the source control area. I see the little icon spinning. So even though I see the large file error in the terminal window. It seems as though it's still attempting to push. What should I do?

Comment: I posted an image of the options I have in VS Code.